# automatically define element IDs on creation

Tags: svg.js

When I create any element in my SVG drawing, if I look at the rendered SVG, it has automatic names like "SvgjsSvg1000". I can modify this ID myself with `element.attr({id:"blah"})`, but is there a way to automatically set the ID to the initial variable name, so it's easier to debug/postprocess the result?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with chaining?

```
var rect1 = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({id:"rect1"});
```

I'm afraid there is no sexier way in svg.js :)

svg.js is on Github btw: https://github.com/wout/svg.js
You could fork it, or request this feature.

Comment: tuning it a bit: `var rect1 = draw.rect(100, 100).id("rect1");`